# Search from database and display it in web page using spring boot + html

Tags: html, spring-boot, sts

Hello guys i am new in spring boot and want to makean function in which i enter a number in my search box and the table related to the data displays on the web page .

[image: I will enter number in search box]

and then info should be visible .
considered me as a noob in spring boot and want to do this fumction plz help
i am using html css for fromt end.
please provide an suitable example for the same i am using controlller class
and thisis my controller class

```
package com.complaintportal.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.complaintportal.entities.tbl_voicechat;
import com.complaintportal.serv.tbl_voicechatservice;

@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
public class Controller {

    /*
     * @Autowired
     * 
     * private tbl_voicechatservice voiceservice;
     */

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Welcome to Complaint Portal");
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/complaint")
    public String complaint(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Complaint lodge");
        return "complaint";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/minutes")
    public String minutes(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Minutes not updated");
        return "minutes";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/unvoicht")
    public String unablevoicechat(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Complaint lodge");
        return "unvoicht";
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "/login";
    }
    
    /*
     * @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{ani}", method = RequestMethod.GET) public
     * tbl_voicechat getDataByANI(@PathVariable("ani") String ani) { return
     * voiceservice.getDataByANI(ani); }
     */

}
```

Please help and provide suitable example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public tbl_voicechat getDataByANI(@RequestParam(name = "ani") String ani) {

```
returnvoiceservice.getDataByANI(ani);
```

}

Your code should work but try using this.

If it does not work share your HTML also.

Comment: i soughted this out and worked completely fine.

Comment: but can u also provide code how ajax can be implemented here